# Unable to pass values from one component to a table component in ReactJS application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I just want to transfer the data from one component to a table component. So after selecting the option from the dropdown menu, it should reflect all the details of that selected option inside the table. I have made two components:

Devdropdown.jsx:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useMemo } from "react";
import Tables from "./Tables";

const Devdropdown = () => {
  const [devices, setDevices] = useState([{}]);
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState();
  const url = "http://localhost:3000/devices";

  useEffect(() => {
    async function getDevices() {
      const response = await fetch(url);
      const body = await response.json();
      setDevices(body.data);
    }
    getDevices();
  }, []);

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setSelected(e.target.value);
  };

  const uniqueDeviceIds = useMemo(
    () => Array.from(new Set(devices.map((device) => device.device_id))),
    [devices]
  );

  console.log(devices);
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Aircraft {selected}</h1>
      <select
        value={selected}
        onChange={handleChange}
        placeholder="select an option"
      >
        {devices
          ? uniqueDeviceIds.map((deviceId) => (
              <option key={deviceId}>{deviceId}</option>
            ))
          : null}
      </select>
      <Tables data={devices[selected]} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Devdropdown;
```

Tables.jsx:

```
import React from "react";

const Tables = (props) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <th>Timestamp</th>
          <th>Location</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>{props.data}</td>
          <td>{props.data}</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Tables;
```

I just want to reflect the timsetamp and location features of the selected element , inside the table. Below is the screenshot of the devices object where I want timestamp and location attributes inside the table component.

[image]

Thanks and regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/Map) to group by your `device_id`, this will allow you to populate your dropdown with unique options by getting the keys of the map (rather than using a `Set`), and also allow you to associate the selected option with an array of `devices` that all have the same `device_id`:

```js
const deviceMap = useMemo(() => {
    const grouped = new Map();
    for (const device of devices) {
      const currDeviceArr = grouped.get(device.device_id) ?? [];
      currDeviceArr.push(device); // add the current device to the associated device_id array
      grouped.set(device.device_id, currDeviceArr);
    }
    return grouped;
  }
  [devices]
);

return (
    <div>
      <h1>Aircraft {selected}</h1>
      <select
        value={selected}
        onChange={handleChange}
        placeholder="select an option"
      >
        {devices
          ? Array.from(deviceMap.keys(), (device_id) => (
              <option key={device_id}>{device_id}</option>
            ))
          : null}
      </select>
      <Tables data={deviceMap.get(selected)} />
    </div>
);
```

Then you can update your `Table` component to map over the devices with the selected device_id:

```js
const Tables = ({ data = []}) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <th>Timestamp</th>
          <th>Location</th>
        </tr>
        {
          data.map((device, i) => <tr key={i}>
            <td>{device.timestamp}</td>
            <td>{device.location}</td>
          </tr>)
        }
      </table>
    </div>
  );
};
```

---

Another approach would be to stick the `Devdropdown` component that you have now, and then filter the `devices` array out based on the selected option, but this isn't as efficient as you now looping over `devices` multiple times:

```
<Tables data={devices.filter(device => device.device_id === selected)} />
```

You could also put the above `.filter()` computation in a `useMemo()` hook so that it only recomputes the array when `devices` or `selected` changes, and not on every rerender. Once you have done this, you can apply the same change to your `Tables` component as shown above.

Comment: What does this line indicate, const currDeviceArr = grouped.get(device.device_id) ?? [];

Can you explain the function?

Comment: The second approach , which is the <Tables data={devices.filter(device => device.device_id === selected)}, is showing:

 Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
    at throwOnInvalidObjectType

Comment: @AnkanChanda It tries to grab the value at the key `device.device_id` from the Map, if the key exists in the Map, then `currDeviceArr` be set the the array stored at that key, otherwise, `currDeviceArr` will default to a new empty array which is that the `?? []` does. If has the same effect as doing `|| []` which you may have seen, but it's a bit different. You can read more about `??` (nullish coalescing) [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing)

Comment: @AnkanChanda You changed `Tables` also as I mentioned right? _"Once you have done this, you can apply the same change to your `Tables` component as shown above."_

Comment: Hey Nick. Sorry, I didn't get you. I did not change anything in Tables component. It is just the same as you can see here. Still the second approach is giving errors that I have mentioned before.

Comment: @AnkanChanda If you look through my answer, I showed a new version of the `Tables` component that you need to use (second code block) for both approaches mentioned. You can use that instead of the `Tables` component you have now

Comment: Ok. Understood. Now after making the changes, it is coming to this:

44  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'device_id')
    at Devdropdown.jsx:44:1
    at Function.from (<anonymous>)
    at Devdropdown (Devdropdown.jsx:40:1)
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:16305:1)
    at mountIndeterminateComponent (react-dom.development.js:20074:1)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:21587:1)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:27426:1)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:26557:1)

Comment: @AnkanChanda Sorry, I had a flaw in the first code snippet. Note that if you're going to use the last code snippet that involves running `.filter()`, then you don't need to change your code to use what's in the first code snippet

Comment: OK. Hey I have made changes with the first code snippet. Can you tell me the flaw, please?

Comment: @AnkanChanda The issue was with `Array.from(deviceMap.keys(), (device) => ( <option key={device.device_id}>{device.device_id}</option>)) : null}`, I was assuming that `device` was a `device` object, but it's actually just the `device_id` from the objects, since I'm getting the `.keys()` on the `deviceMap`, and the keys of the Map are set to the device_ids, not device objects. So I changed it to `Array.from(deviceMap.keys(), (device_id) => ( <option key={device_id}>{device_id}</option>)) : null}`. The change is updated already in my answer above.

Comment: Can you explain me about the ({data =[]}) in props of Tables component? Is the data being declared as an empty array at first? How come it is getting mapped inside? Please can you explain it briefly.

Comment: @AnkanChanda It's a default value in case `data` is passed a value of `undefined`, it will use an empty array instead. The `selected` state starts off as `undefined` because you don't pass a value to `useState()`. So in the beginning, there's no value in the `Map` for the `selected` value of `undefined`. That means that the value passed to the `data` prop will be `undefined ` as `deviceMap.get(selected)` returns `undefined` when it can't find the key passed to `.get()` in the map. In `Tables`, we don't want to call `.map()` on `undefined`, otherwise it will give an error, so w default it

Comment: Ok. Got it. So default value needs to get established at first. I thought that the moment I am providing value to the selected variable through dropdown, that value should be fetched at first.

Comment: In this line, what key value can we give? 
<Tables data={deviceMap.get(selected)} />

Warning sign is being shown as 

ntime.development.js:87  Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.

Check the render method of `Devdropdown`. See https://reactjs.org/link/warning-keys for more information.
    at option
    at Devdropdow

Comment: @AnkanChanda that error shouldn't be appearing, in both examples above we're supplying a `key` prop to the mapped JSX elements, and the key is unique for each element. Might want to check that you're not performing a map somewhere and forgetting the `key` prop.

Comment: In this line, <Tables data={deviceMap.get(selected)} key={deviceMap.get(selected)} />, is the key needed when passing props to Tables component? When using map I have given the key value, like you've given. Still its coming to an error.

Comment: @AnkanChanda No a `key` isn't needed for that since `<Tables ... />` isn't being used or returned directly from a `.map()` method, so the warning shouldn't be coming from that.

Comment: The error is still coming.

Comment: Have one thing to clear about. So, in this line, <Tables data={deviceMap.get(selected)} />
, after the selected element has an option from the dropdown, in the deviceMap , the selected element gets checked in here, const currDeviceArr = grouped.get(device.device_id) ?? []; ?? Is that so?
Actually there hasn't been any parameters in the deviceMap() that's why, am asking

Comment: @AnkanChanda Not sure about the warning. That shouldn't be appearing with the above code. No, the code within the `useMemo()` only runs when `devices` changes to create the Map (`deviceMap`). The Map keys and values 
 that we set in the `useMemo()` can then be accessed using `.get()`, which is what we're doing here `<Tables data={deviceMap.get(selected)} />`. This code reruns on every rerender (which occurs when you update `selected` with `setSelected(...)`). I suggest `console.log(deviceMap)` to see what it looks like, and to check out the Map docs, it should give you a better idea then

Comment: Ok. Can the same thing, <Charts data={deviceMap.get(selected)} /> be run incase of Pie Charts? I was passing like the above and want to fetch locations of particular {selected} items , making them as labels like , L1, L2... L6. Can we do that? I was trying but it says , Cannot read undefined. I have passed data = [] like the one sent in Tables component, but its of no use.